# Nested Loops AND SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

My question is regarding SQL and PHP. Specifically, nesting a loop inside another loop that both grab information from the server. I’m unsure if I’m going about this the right way.

Essentially, for every row of data from table 1(customer table), I want to check if a value matches from both tables in column 1(the unique ID), and if it does, grab that whole matching row(or multiple rows) from table two(orders) and insert that below each consecutive row from table one as the function iterates through both tables data.

My code is something like this;

```
$table1 = “SELECT * FROM customers”;
$table2 = “SELECT * FROM orders”;

$query_table1 = $link-> query($table1);
$query_table2 = $link-> query($table2);

while ($customer = $query_table1 → fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $customer;
    while ($order = $query_table2 → fetch_assoc()) {
      if ($order[“customer_id”] === $customer[“customer_id”]) {
        echo $order;
}
}
}
```

The result is that I get all the output from table 1, then nothing from table 2.
If I remove the if, I get row 1 table 1, then all of table 2, then the rest of table 1.

I'm using html tables to render the data. What I want is -> customer -> their orders(if any) -> next customer -> their orders, until the iteration ends.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: join the tables and run only 1 query

Comment: The nested loops won't work because when you reach the end of the inner loop, there won't be any rows to read during the next iteration of the outer loop. If you're going to use nested loops, you should perform a separate query for the related rows.

Comment: Thanks nbk. @Barmar. I was thinking it was similar to js. So I have to create a while for each of the individual rows then? Thank you.

Comment: You could use `fetch_all()` to get all the results as an array, then loop over that as many times as you want.

Comment: But the best solution is to join the tables: `SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders USING (customer_id) ORDER BY customer_id, order_id`

Comment: BTW, `echo $customer` and `echo $order` won't work. You can't echo an array (it just prints the word `Array`). Use `var_dump()` to see array contents.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks, that makes sense. I'll give it a go.